# How to write a Trigger that Adds a $2 late penalty to a members unpaid balance account

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, oracle10g

I want to create a trigger that enforces that a late return penalty is $2 each day late. The fine should automatically be calculated and added to the balance. Below is my code as well as my attempt for the trigger. The trigger only accounts for the rental code of one day, but if I can figure out one of the rental codes, the other two will be easy to figure out.

What Trigger code i have so far:

```
Create or Replace Trigger Late_Rule
BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
For each Row
DECLARE
NofDays NUMBER; 
ChargeDays Number;
Fee Number;

BEGIN

SELECT count(Rental_Code) into NofDays
From Transaction Group by Mem_num having  Mem_num= :new.Mem_num;
 DBMS_output.put_line(NofDays);

If Rental_Code = 'R101'
 If (Date_Rented_Out - Date_returned) > 1
    NofDays- 1 = ChargeDays
    ChargeDays * 2 = Fee
ELSE 
Fee = 0
  END IF;
END IF;

Update Fee into Unpaid_Bal

end;
/


  show error;
```

---

```
--Attempt 2

Create or replace trigger Late_Fee_Rule
Before UPDATE ON transaction
for each row
DECLARE
Fine_Due NUMBER;
BEGIN
SET Fine_Due = trunc(sysdate - date_rented_out) * 2
where date_returned is null
and (sysdate - date_rented_out) > decode (Rental_code, 'R101', 1, 'R103', 3, 'R105', 5);
Update Member
where Unpaid_Bal = (Unpaid_Bal + Fine_Due)


End;
/
show error;
```

Comment: The wonderful thing about tiggers is that tiggers a wonderful thing.

Comment: It might be a good idea to set up a SQL Fiddle instead of cluttering SO with your entire data model every time you ask a question about Tiggers, er, Triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any data (such as fine due) will change continuously (e.g. every day), then don't store it in your model at all.

Instead, calculate it at report time using a view, e.g. (adapted from APC's example):

```
CREATE transaction_vw AS
SELECT t.*
      ,CASE WHEN date_returned is null
             and (sysdate - date_returned_out)
               > DECODE(rental_code
                       ,'R101', 1
                       ,'R103', 3
                       ,'R105', 5)
       THEN trunc(sysdate - date_returned_out) * 2
       END AS fine_due
FROM transaction t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked several questions about Triggers recently, so I presume you are learning about them.  However, you have reached the point at which a Trigger is not appropriate for the business logic you need to implement.

1. Embedded queries like this don't scale well.
2. In a multi-session environment the logic may produce the wrong result.
3. From a business perspective, the fine is being added to the wrong transaction.
4. Also from a business perspective, there is no visibility of fines due until the errant member rents another movie.
5. triggers like this make maintenance more difficult because they hide business rules where people don't expect them.

That it is difficult for you to write the trigger is an indicator that you are on the wrong path.  The better solution would be to use a database job to check all the unreturned movies once a day and calculate the fine due for each transaction.  It looks like you intend to have a fine due column on the TRANSACTION table: that is one approach.  Life is slightly harder because the rental period is a string code rather than the number of days, and you don't store the due back date.

```
update transaction
set fine_due = trunc(sysdate - date_returned_out) * 2
where date_returned is null
and (sysdate - date_returned_out) > decode (rental_code, 'R101', 1, 'R103', 3, 'R105', 5)
/
```

Comment: I have gone ahead and attempted to follow your changes with a second attempt I posted at the bottom

Comment: I get the following errors,      LINE/COL 
ERROR 

4/1  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
4/5  PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: Please re-read my answer.  I'm suggesting an update statement in a background job *instead of* doing something in a trigger.

Comment: What you really need is a trigger that executes when the amount the customer owes is queried. Gee, that sounds like a calculated field in a view. And listen to @APC: model the data with an eye to functionality rather than format. And keep details like the association between late days and rental codes in a separate table, not in trigger code.